How to tell if a force on a rigid body does any work?
In problems in Newtonian mechanics I often need to understand whether there is energy conservation. When only conservative forces (such as gravity) are present, it's obvious. But what about when we also have some potentially non-conservative forces. E.g. some normal force against a surface?
When dealing only with point particles (oh the good old days of a month ago), the answer is clear. If the force is acting in the direction perpendicular to the velocity of the particle - it does no work.
However - rigid bodies seem to be more complicated. Suppose a (non-conservative) force $F$ is acting in the rigid body, at some application point P.
How should I determine whether it does or doesn't do work?

Does it do no-work if the velocity of the point of contact is perpendicular to the force?

Does it do no-work if the velocity of the center of mass is perpendicular to the force?


I hope my question is clear. Thank you

Does the point of application of the force move in the direction of the force?

@Farcher So let's suppose that the point of application is moving in the perpendicular direction to the direction of the force. Does this mean that the force does no work?

Suppose a horizontal force is applied onto a book which pushes it against a vertical wall.  However, the book is slipping down under the influence of gravity.  The horizontal force does no work.

@Farcher I understand. However - does the horizontal force do no work, because the center of mass of the book is moving in a perpendicular direction to the horizontal force? Or is it because the point of contact of the force and the book is moving in a perpendicular direction to the force?

The second reason is my choice.

@AvivCohn It is important to remember that $$\int_1^2\vec F\cdot d\vec s_{\text{COM}},$$ is not in general the work done on a rigid body.

Suppose we consider a ladder leaning against a wall in such a way that the ladder makes an angle $\theta$ with respect to the floor, further, there is no friction so that the ladder slides down the wall.
Now, taking the ladder as the mechanical system under consideration, it has the following forces on it, a normal force pointing upward from the point of contact at the floor, a normal force pointing out from the wall from the point of contact at the wall and the force of gravity pointing downward from the center of mass of the ladder. In each case of the normal force, the motion of the ladder at the contact points is perpendicular to the normal force, thus the normal forces do no work on the ladder, they are merely forces of constraint. The gravitational force, on the other hand, can be considered as acting on the center of mass, which does do work on the ladder. For example, the gravitational force points straight downward from the center of mass, and the center of mass moves both straight downward and straight outward from the wall, parallel to the floor, thus the product $\vec W\cdot d\vec s_{\text{com}}\neq 0$.
So let's work through the details of an example, such as that we discussed, of a ladder of mass $m$ and length $2L$, leaning up against a wall initially at angle $\theta_0$. Working in the fashion of textbooks like Kleppner and Kolenkow, let us first calculate the work done on the ladder over the course of it's motion from $\theta_0$ to $\theta$. Now, Kleppner and Kolenkow do not use the usual definition of work, i.e.
$$W=\int_C\sum_i \vec F_i\cdot d\vec r_i,$$
where $d\vec r_i$ is understood as the displacement of the point of contact where the force $\vec F_i$ acts, rather the authors understand work to correspond to the integral of Newton's second law:
$$W=\int_C\sum_i\vec F_i\cdot d\vec r_{\text{CM}}+\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}|\vec \tau_0|\;d\theta.$$
Thus, to compute the "work" in the fashion of Kleppner and Kolenkow, for the ladder, we have to consider the action of the forces on the center of mass:
$$W_{\text{trans}}=\int_C \sum_i\vec F_i\cdot d\vec r_{\text{CM}}
=\int_C [\vec F_g+\vec N_w+\vec N_f]\cdot d\vec r_{\text{CM}}.$$
And also:
$$W_{\text{rot}}=\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}\vec\tau_0|\;d\theta
=\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}(\vec r\times(\vec N_w+\vec N_f)\;d\theta
=\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}L(-|\vec N_w|\sin\theta+|\vec N_f|\cos\theta)\;d\theta.$$
Now, it is known that the ladder will slip down the wall until the top reaches some fraction of it's initial height, we can see this as follows. Since there are no dissipative forces, energy is conserved, $\Delta E=\Delta K+\Delta U=0$. We have therefore,
$$0={1\over 2}mV_{\text{CM}}^2+{1\over 6}mL^2\omega^2+Lmg(\sin\theta-\sin\theta_0),$$
or
$$0={2\over 3}mL^2\omega^2+Lmg(\sin\theta-\sin\theta_0),$$
where the translational kinetic term has been written in it's angular form.
Taking the derivative of the energy relation we get:
$$0={4\over 3}L\dot\omega+g\cos\theta.$$
$$\implies \dot\omega=-{3g\over 4L}\cos\theta.$$
Since the horizontal component of the center of mass' position is $x=L\cos\theta$, it's acceleration is accordingly given by $\ddot x=-L(\dot\omega\sin\theta+\omega^2\cos\theta)$. Now when the ladder detaches from the wall, the horizontal component of force provided by the constraint of the wall disappears so that $\ddot x=0$. This condition implies that:
$$0=\dot\omega\sin\theta+\omega^2\cos\theta\implies\dot\omega=-\omega^2\cot\theta.$$
So that we get that by substituting the above into the expression for $\dot\omega$:
$$\omega^2\cot\theta={3g\over 4L}\cos\theta\implies\omega^2={3g\over 4L}\sin\theta.$$
Plugging this result into the energy relation, we get:
$$0={1\over 2}\sin\theta+\sin\theta-\sin\theta_0\implies\sin\theta={2\over 3}\sin\theta_0,$$
which is the desired result.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Hey, I'd like to clarify something about my understanding if that's alright. From what I understand from you: A. The correct way to compute work for an individual force, is to use a line integral of the force along the curve traced by the point of contact of the force and the body. B. The correct way to get the total work done on an object in the general case, is to sum all of the work done by the N individual forces acting on the object, each work computed as mentioned in A. Continuing next comment:

C. Additionally, you explained that there's a concept called "pseudo-work". The total pseudo-work on an object is computed like so (as explained in my textbook by Kleppner and Kolenkow): $W = \int_c \Sigma{\vec{F}} \cdot d\vec{r_{com}} + \int_{\phi{1}}^{\phi{2}} \vec{\tau} d\phi$, where $\vec{\tau}$ is the total torque on the object, and the two angles are the beginning and end angles of rotation of the object around its CoM. C is the path traced by the CoM of the object.

So the question is: would computing the total work done using this "pseudowork" method, yield the same result as computing the total work done using the method described in point B above?

Also, please confirm if my understanding is correct regarding points A, B, and C. I'm sorry if I'm reiterating stuff we already discussed, just trying to retain my understanding.

@AvivCohn Looks like you are getting it all, however, as regards work and pseudowork: Pseudowork is the work done by considering all the forces as acting on the center of mass, and sometimes this is the same as calculating work, however, not all the time. One can define rigid body systems for which the pseudowork and work are different.

@AlbertusMagnus I see. However when we take into account the integral over the total torque, as shown in the formula I wrote above, doesn't that adjust for the error and make psuedowork and total work identical?

@AvivCohn Only sometimes, e.g. a cylinder rolling down an inclined plane; both forms of work give the same numerical value. Consider the following: a system consisting of two masses $m_1$ and $m_2$, equally spaced about the origin, with each mass acted upon by equal and opposite respective forces $F_1$ and $F_2$. The center of mass remains at the origin despite displacement of the masses by a distance $d$ each, so the pseudowork done on the system is zero. On the other hand, the work done on the system is $(F_1+F_2)d$.

@AvivCohn Basically, pseudowork methods and work methods always agree whenever the system is a point mass, however, they differ for systems of more that one particle, sometimes the difference is slight and subtle (cylinder olling down an inclined plane), and sometimes drastic (two blocks example).

As long as the contact point moves in the direction of the force then you do work on the rigid body.
Consider this: Thread a disk with a hole in the center onto a frictionless straight rod,the rod is perpendicular to the disk.Give the disk a velocity along the rod.Then excert a force on the edge of the disk parallel to the disk's surface.The disk will start to rotate because of the work done by the force,yet the center of mass moves in a perpendicular direction to the force.
Because the movement of the center of mass can only reflect the translational motion of the rigid body,while work can be done to make the body rotate.Afterall,if you do work on the contact point,you definitely do work on the body,for we take the body as a system.


How to tell if a force on a rigid body does any work?

A force does work on a rigid body when it transfers energy to the body (positive work) or takes energy away from the body (negative work). For that to occur translational or rotational displacement of the body must occur at the point of application due to the force.

Suppose a (non-conservative) force $F$ is acting in the rigid body, at
some application point P. How should I determine whether it does or doesn't do work?

You should apply the criteria stated above for the case of non-conservative forces. Examples of non-conservative forces to consider are friction (e.g., dry, fluid, internal) air resistance/drag and push-pull forces.


Does it do no-work if the velocity of the point of contact is perpendicular to the force?


It depends on the relationship between the force and the velocity.
The force can be doing work if it is causing displacement of the body at the point of contact while a component of the body's velocity is perpendicular to the direction of the force at the point of contact.
FIG 1 shows a rigid body falling under the influence of gravity (a conservative force) in the presence of a constant horizontal pushing (non conservative) force. The pushing force is doing work displacing the rigid body horizontally.  At the same time gravity is doing work giving the body vertical velocity perpendicular to the force.
In most instances, however, non-conservative forces would not be doing work. FIG 2 shows a free body diagram of the same rigid body sliding down between two surfaces, one friction free and one with friction, in the presence horizontal pushing forces, a drag force due to air, and the force of gravity.

The non-conservative horizontal pushing force on the left and perpendicular to the motion of the body does no work as it causes no horizontal displacement of the rigid body.

The reaction pushing force  on the right of the body perpendicular to its motion likewise does no work.

The non-conservative kinetic friction force $f_f$ acts parallel to and opposite in direction to the body's motion. It does negative work taking kinetic energy away from the body and dissipating it as heat. Note that the kinetic friction force would not exist without the pushing force $F$ normal to the surface.

The non-conservative drag force due to air resistance acts opposite to the displacement of the body. It does negative work taking kinetic energy from the body and dissipating it as heat.

Finally, the conservative gravitational force in the direction of the body's motion does positive work.




Does it do no-work if the velocity of the center of mass is perpendicular to the force?


I'm not sure about the distinction between this and your first question. Perhaps you could elaborate further. The answers to your first question all involve the velocity of the center of mass.
Hope this helps.



For a rigid body you check the power that a specific loading condition provides to the body. If power is positive then work is added, if negative then work is removed and if zero then no work is done.
The choice of location where you sum up the quantities does not matter. Let us designate point C as the center of mass and point A an arbitrary point on the body (or in space co-moving with the body).
Power $P$ is calculated as follows
$$ P = \boldsymbol{v}_A \cdot \boldsymbol{F} + \boldsymbol{\omega} \cdot \boldsymbol{\tau}_A $$
where $\cdot$ is the vector dot product and



Symbol
Quantity




$\boldsymbol{v}_A$
Velocity vector at point A


$\boldsymbol{F}$
Force vector acting on body


$\boldsymbol{\omega}$
Rotational velocity vector of body


$\boldsymbol{\tau}_A$
Equipollent torque vector summed at point A



Now if you define the quantities at A as a function of the quantities at the center of mass C with
$$ \boldsymbol{v}_A = \boldsymbol{v}_C - \boldsymbol{\omega} \times \boldsymbol{r}$$
and
$$ \boldsymbol{\tau}_A = \boldsymbol{\tau}_C + \boldsymbol{r} \times \boldsymbol{F} $$
where $\boldsymbol{r}$ is the position of the center of mass relative to the arbitrary point.
Power is then
$$ \begin{aligned}P & =\boldsymbol{v}_{A}\cdot\boldsymbol{F}+\boldsymbol{\omega}\cdot\boldsymbol{\tau}_{A}\\
 & =(\boldsymbol{v}_{C}-\boldsymbol{\omega}\times\boldsymbol{r})\cdot\boldsymbol{F}+\boldsymbol{\omega}\cdot(\boldsymbol{\tau}_{C}+\boldsymbol{r}\times\boldsymbol{F})\\
 & =\boldsymbol{v}_{C}\cdot\boldsymbol{F}-(\boldsymbol{\omega}\times\boldsymbol{r})\cdot\boldsymbol{F}+\boldsymbol{\omega}\cdot\boldsymbol{\tau}_{C}+\boldsymbol{\omega}\cdot(\boldsymbol{r}\times\boldsymbol{F})\\
 & =\boldsymbol{v}_{C}\cdot\boldsymbol{F}+\boldsymbol{\omega}\cdot\boldsymbol{\tau}_{C}
\end{aligned}
$$
which shows that the location at which velocity and torque is evaluated does not matter, as power is a spatial invariant quantity.
From power, one can evaluate kinetic energy also as the dot product of motion with momentum
$$ KE = \tfrac{1}{2} \boldsymbol{v}_A \cdot \boldsymbol{p} + \tfrac{1}{2} \boldsymbol{\omega} \cdot \boldsymbol{L}_A $$
where $p = m \boldsymbol{v}_C$ is momentum, and $L_A = {\rm I}_C \boldsymbol{\omega} + \boldsymbol{r} \times \boldsymbol{p}$ is angular momentum at A.
Kinetic energy is also spatially invariant as you can similarly show that
$$KE = \tfrac{1}{2} \boldsymbol{v}_C \cdot \boldsymbol{p} + \tfrac{1}{2} \boldsymbol{\omega} \cdot \boldsymbol{L}_C = \tfrac{1}{2} \boldsymbol{v}_C \cdot (m \boldsymbol{v}_C) + \tfrac{1}{2} \boldsymbol{\omega} \cdot ( {\rm I}_C \boldsymbol{\omega}) $$
